# Route with a query string is passed to incorrect controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, rails-api

With my rails api. At the moment if I do a get request to /seasons/2 I correctly have a json returned with the season table item of id= 2 through the Seasons controller show action.

But when I hit a get request to /seasons?id=2 a json is returned with all the season resources with the controller Index Action being hit, instead of the show action.

Below is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'application#not_found'
  
  resources :seasons do
    
  end


end
```

Seasons controller:

```
class SeasonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_season, only: [:show]

  def index
    @seasons = Season.all
    json_response(@seasons)
  end

  def show
    json_response(@season)
  end

  private

  

  def set_season
    @season = Season.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My belief was that rails routing should assign both /seasons/2 and /seasons?id=2 to the show controller action by default

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work that way. `GET /seasons` is an `#index` call, `GET /seasons/:id` is a `#show` call. The query (`?id=2`) is considered *after* the URL path has been used to figure out which controller method to call.

Answer (score -1):

try with this:

```
// routes.rb

....
resources :seasons, only: [:index, :show]
...
```

After, check your routes on your terminal with the following command:

```
rails routes
```